# I am trying to make a todo list in javascript but the HTML doesn't show it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to code a todo list in javascript, but somehow it doesn't work.

this is my JavaScript and HTML:

```js
let todos = [] 
function createTodo() {
    let newTodo = {
        text: '',
        checked: 0
    }
    newTodo['text'] = prompt('Item description')
    todos.push(newTodo)
    
}

for (i in todos) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li')
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(i['text'])
    console.log('itemText: ' + itemText)
    listItem.appendChild(itemText)
    console.log('listItem: ' + listItem)
    document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="createTodo();">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the todo button it prompts me for text, and when i type in the console it does show that it's been pushed; but when iterated with a for loop it shows 'undefined' in the console, plus it doesn't even show up in the HTML. Please help me.

Comment: Calling `createTodo()` simply pushes the item in the Array. It does not change the HTML. You only change the HTML when the page first loads, in your `for` loop

Comment: When you loop in `todos`, variable `i` returns the index of the element, not the element. So `i['text']` should be `todos[i]['text']` or `todos[i].text`.

Comment: No, i is the actual element, he's looping through the list. The problem was he never updated the actual HTML after he added to the list. The loop only ran once; in the beginning.

Comment: @EpixyCoder101, above code has both problems (not updating html and `i` is not the element but the index). Try running this code `for(i in ['a','b']) { console.log(i) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your code, there is nowhere to add created elements to HTML.
And when it comes to open prompt, you should get value from the input.

This is how to get input value and reflects it to the HTML

```
let todos = []
function createTodo() {
    let newTodo = {
        text: '',
        checked: 0
    }
    newTodo['text'] = prompt('Item description')
    if( newTodo.text != null ) {
        todos.push(newTodo)
        reflectToHtml(newTodo)
    }
}
function reflectToHtml(i) {
    let listItem = document.createElement('li')
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(i['text'])
    listItem.appendChild(itemText)
    document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
    document.getElementById('item-count').innerText = todos.length
}
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, how can I add a checkbox next to each list and be able to reflect whether it's checked or not in the HTML? Sorry for the dumb question, I'm not used to web development.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try:

```js
let todos = []
for (i in todos) {
  let listItem = document.createElement('li')
  let itemText = document.createTextNode(i.text)
  alert('itemText: ' + itemText)
  listItem.appendChild(itemText)
  alert('listItem: ' + listItem)
  document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
}

function createTodo() {
  let newTodo = {
    text: '',
    checked: 0
  }
  var addTodo = prompt('Item description');
  newTodo.text = addTodo;
  todos.push(newTodo);
  let listItem = document.createElement('li')
  let itemText = document.createTextNode(newTodo.text)
  alert("Added new todo. Todo:\n" + addTodo);
  listItem.appendChild(itemText)
  document.getElementById('todo-list').appendChild(listItem)
  alert("Succesfuly created todo.");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TODO App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container center">
    <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
    <div class="flow-right controls">
      <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
      <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
    </div>
    <button class="button center" onClick="createTodo();">New TODO</button>
    <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem was that when your program first ran, it appended an empty list to the div. Then, you appended the item to the list of todos. The loop won't run again. I changed this code slightly. NOW, it adds it to the list, but its main functionality is that it directly appends the item to the list. This solution should work. There are other ways, but this one is the most convenient, personally.